# Strong convexity, non-smoothness, and directional derivative

Tags: derivatives, convex-optimization

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is (strongly) convex (say in $\mathbb{R}^n$), but not necessarily differentiable. It attains its minimum at $\mathbf{q}$. Given two vectors $\mathbf{w},\mathbf{p}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, I would like to know if I can use the fact that $(\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{q})^\top(\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{p})\ge0$ to show that the directional derivative $f'(\mathbf{p};\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{p})$ is greater or equal than zero, where $f'(\mathbf{p};\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{p})=\text{inf}_{t>0}\frac{f(\mathbf{p}+t(\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{p}))-f(\mathbf{p})}{t}$. Intuitively, it should be (from my point of view), but I'm having a hard time to figure out how to show it. Any help would be appreciated.

Function $f$ is related to the function being minimized in a proximal operator, in case it matters.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, user251257. The problem in this case is that the minimizer is $q$, and not $p$.

Comment: oh, my bad. sorry

Comment: I do not think it is true without extra conditions. If you place $q$ between $w$ and $p$ then $w-p$ and $w-q$ have the same direction, i.e. scalar product is positive, however, $w-p$ points from $p$ towards $q$ and the derivative is likely to be negative. For example, for $n=1$, $q=0$, $w=-p=1$ and $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: @A.G. 9 seconds earlier D: :D

Comment: @user251257 Well, you have different signs for $p$ and $w$ too :-)

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks for your help, A.G. and user251257.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = \frac12 x^2$ for $x\in\mathbb R$, $q=0$, $p=1$, $w = -1$.
Then, we have $(w-q)(w-p) = -1(-2) = 2 \ge 0$ and $f'(1)(-2) = -2 < 0$.